# How to remove value from the Y axis in MP Android BarChart

Tags: java, android, graph, mpandroidchart

I have created a bar graph with MPAndroid, but i want the chart minimal as possible so i removed most the description, grid and Ledgers. But i can't figure out how to remove these values from the chart.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with this code:

```
chart.getAxisLeft().setDrawLabels(false);  
chart.getAxisRight().setDrawLabels(false);
```